# remove file that "is outside repository" in GIT

Tags: git, repository

I have a file that is loitering in my `git status` saying it has been deleted, but when I try to `git rm` is, I get `***/***.php is outside repository`. The folder it is in is certainly within the repo, so I am confused!

Comment: Does it exist for real? What happens if you just `rm` (not `git rm`) it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is strange. But perhaps you just need to commit your changes? `git status` lists changes that have been staged but not committed yet. If you `git commit` your changes, `git status` shouldn't list the file as deleted anymore.

Comment: very much one of those "I swear that wasn't working" moments. :D

Answer (score 5):

I have struggled with a similar problem for a long time turns out that a simple but not intutive switch was the answer.

`git add --update` or just `git add -u`

will add modified files and remove deleted files.

And if you want to add new files as well:
`git add --all` or `git add -A`

will add new files, modified files and remove deleted files.

Kudos to [Geek Gumbo](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/05/16/removing-deleted-files-from-your-git-working-directory/)

And for more serious documentation check [Git SCM](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)